# Numbering rows in a view

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2000

I am connecting to an SQL database using a PLC, and need to return a list of values. Unfortunately, the PLC has limited memory, and can only retrieve approximately 5,000 values at any one time, however the database may contain up to 10,000 values.

As such I need a way of retrieving these values in 2 operations. Unfortunately the PLC is limited in the query it can perform, and is limited to only SELECT and WHERE commands, so I cannot use LIMIT or TOP or anything like that.

Is there a way in which I can create a view, and auto number every field in that view? I could then query all records < 5,000, followed by a second query of < 10,000 etc?

Unfortunately it seems that views do not support the identity column, so this would need to be done manually.

Anyone any suggestions? My only realistic option at the moment seems to be to create 2 views, one with the first 5,000 and 1 with the next 5,000...

I am using SQL Server 2000 if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code provided by Derek does what I asked - i.e numbers each row in the view, the performance for this is really poor - approximately 20 seconds to number 100 rows. As such it is not a workable solution. An alternative is to number the first 5,000 records with a 1, and the next 5,000 with a 2. This can be done with 3 simple queries, and is far quicker to execute.

The code to do so is as follows:

```
SELECT TOP(5000) BCode, SAPCode, 1 as GroupNo FROM dbo.DB 
UNION
SELECT TOP (10000) BCode, SAPCode, 2 as GroupNo FROM dbo.DB p 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP(5000) ID FROM dbo.DB)
```

Although, as pointed out by Andriy M, you should also specify an explicit sort, to ensure the you dont miss any records.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions. The easiest is to modify your SQL table and add an `IDENTITY` column. If that is not a possibility, the you'll have to do something like the below query. For 10000 rows, it shouldn't be too slow. But as the table grows, it will become worse and worse-performing.

```
SELECT        Col1, Col2, (SELECT COUNT(i.Col1) 
               FROM yourtable i 
               WHERE i.Col1 <= o.Col1) AS RowID
FROM          yourtable o
```

Comment: Thanks, Derek, while that works and numbers them, it takes 20 seconds to number 100 records on my test database, so that isn't going to work too well with 10,000 rows! I have instead found a way to number the first 5,000 with a 1, and the second 5,000 with a 2, we can then query on that instead.

Comment: The code mentioned above is as follows:

`SELECT TOP(5000) BCode, SAPCode, 1 as GroupNo FROM dbo.DB
union
SELECT TOP (10000) BCode, SAPCode, 2 as GroupNo
FROM         dbo.DB p
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP(5000) ID FROM dbo.DB)`

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution - you can post it as a separate "Answer" and accept your own answer so anyone that runs into this problem will see your end-solution.

Comment: @Gavin Coates: Without an explicit ORDER BY you are not guaranteed to always obtain the same 5000 rows in both cases. The problem may never arise, yet that is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to use a function with a temporary table such as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.OrderedBCodeData()
RETURNS @Data TABLE (RowNumber int IDENTITY(1,1),BCode int,SAPCode int)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Data (BCode,SAPCode)
    SELECT BCode,SAPCode FROM dbo.DB ORDER BY BCode

    RETURN
END
```

And select from this function such as

```
SELECT FROM dbo.OrderedBCodeData() WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
```

I haven't used this in production ever, in fact was just a quick idea this morning but worth exploring as a neater alternative?

Comment: Thanks Justin - that sounds like it might work, however we have decided to go with the option I mentioned in my post. We are communicating to the database from a PLC, which has very limited support for SQL.. I am not sure if it will support calls to DB functions.